# Palty pregnant fish

Tags: pregnancy

[image]

Been reading through everything and every site I could find my female platy looks huge now think she it pregnant as when I purchased the fish I had bought 3 that where already pregnant according to the pet store. In the picture is the platy in question is got huge and is showing aggression to the rest of the fish and she is hiding a lot as well as not coming out for food. Can anyone advice me what I should do as I've had problem in the past with fish from this store. [image]